# Text on axis ticks not being generated with d3 and Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, d3.js, cross-browser, axis-labels

I have been working on a visualization project with d3 for some time now, but I only just now checked how it worked with Firefox. And it did not work very well... I have been able to fix some of the issues, but one thing that I can't get to work is that on some of the axis, the text that is supposed to come next to the ticks are missing. The label on the axis still works, but not the labeling of the ticks. The text is not misplaced or anything, when I inspect the element I see an empty tag for the text, but no actual text inside it...Here is a link to the web page:
http://www.it-stud.hiof.no/~juliemr/master2/prototypes/priotesting.html

The code is a terrible mess, and I don't know what I should paste of it, but here is an example of one of the graphs were the tick text is not being added (in Firefox, works in Chrome):

```
// The x & y axes.
xAxisb = d3.svg.axis().orient("top").scale(hackScale2).ticks(3,d3.format(",d")).orient("bottom");
yAxisb = d3.svg.axis().scale(byScale).orient("left");

 // Create the SVG container 
 svgdemocracy = d3.select("#bchart1").append("svg")
.attr("width", bwidth + bmargin.left + bmargin.right + "px")
.attr("height", bheight + bmargin.top + bmargin.bottom + "px")
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + bmargin.left + 100 + "," + bmargin.top + ")");

 // Add the x-axis.
 svgdemocracy.append("g")
.attr("class", "x axisb")
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + bheight + ")")
.call(xAxisb);

 // Add the y-axis.
 svgdemocracy.append("g")
.attr("class", "y axisb")
.call(yAxisb);

// Add an x-axis label.
 svgdemocracy.append("text")
.attr("class", "x label")
.attr("text-anchor", "end")
.attr("x", bwidth /2 - 20 )
.attr("y", bheight +15)
.text("Democracies");

// Add a y-axis label.
svgdemocracy.append("text")
.attr("class", "y label")
.attr("text-anchor", "end")
.attr("y", 6)
.attr("dy", ".75em")
.attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
.text("gdp per capita");
```

I have another issue with Firefox as well: It is generally super slow with all the visualizations and selecting elements on the map and so forth. I am using a librabry from Mike Bostock for zooming and panning (d3-zoom-pan-extent.js), which generates an error *"mutating the [[Prototype]] of an object will cause your code to run very slowly; instead create the object with the correct initial [[Prototype]] value using Object.create"*

Is this what causes the whole thing to be so slow in Firefox?